# Why does my bluetooth disconnect after ~3 mins?

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth, journalctl

This wasn't a problem until about a month ago. Now, whenever I connect to any bluetooth speaker, it'll disconnect after about 3 mins, usually when idle, but sometimes not. Here's the output of journalctl during a disconnect:

```
May 17 15:06:20 archweaponevo kernel: usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 91
May 17 15:06:20 archweaponevo dbus-daemon[371]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.25" (uid=1000 pid=635 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.3" (uid=0 pid=390 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd ")
May 17 15:06:20 archweaponevo bluetoothd[390]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.25 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
May 17 15:06:20 archweaponevo bluetoothd[390]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.25 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
May 17 15:06:20 archweaponevo systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
May 17 15:06:20 archweaponevo NetworkManager[372]: <info>  [1621281980.8775] device (A0:10:81:38:A2:7D): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
May 17 15:06:20 archweaponevo systemd[483]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
May 17 15:06:20 archweaponevo systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
May 17 15:06:20 archweaponevo systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
May 17 15:06:20 archweaponevo audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
May 17 15:06:20 archweaponevo kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1621281980.880:3435): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
May 17 15:06:20 archweaponevo kernel: usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 92 using ehci-pci
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo kernel: usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0a5c, idProduct=21e6, bcdDevice= 1.12
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo kernel: usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo kernel: usb 1-1.4: Product: BCM20702A0
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo kernel: usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo kernel: usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: F4B7E2CCD8D1
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo upowerd[650]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo systemd[483]: Reached target Bluetooth.
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: archweaponevo
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e6.hcd'
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-0a5c-21e6.hcd'
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo bluetoothd[390]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.25 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo bluetoothd[390]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.25 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo NetworkManager[372]: <info>  [1621281981.8185] manager: (A0:10:81:38:A2:7D): new Bluetooth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/91)
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo NetworkManager[372]: <info>  [1621281981.8192] device (A0:10:81:38:A2:7D): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 17 15:06:21 archweaponevo NetworkManager[372]: <info>  [1621281981.8219] device (A0:10:81:38:A2:7D): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 17 15:06:26 archweaponevo systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 17 15:06:26 archweaponevo audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
May 17 15:06:26 archweaponevo kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1621281986.064:3436): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

I can solve the problem temporarily with Powertop by toggling "Autosuspend for USB device BCM20702A0 [Broadcom Corp]".

Running `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.4/power/control`
Confirms the change and bluetooth seems to stay connected. But rebooting resets it.

I've tried adding a udev rule like this:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/usb-power.rules:
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0a5c", ATTR{idProduct}=="21e6", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="on"
```

But this had no effect.

Comment: I had a similar problem on arch linux with my headphones and it was caused by the USB auto suspend.  You can pass in a boot option `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` to disable it.  Maybe this will help if I remember correctly the arch wiki has a good section on this also.

Comment: @JasonCroyle Thanks. Your hint pointed me in the right direction. I used powertop to disable auto-suspend and things look good so far.

Comment: @JasonCroyle Turns out to be a temporary solution. Resets on reboot :(

Comment: its been awhile from when I had the issue but that maybe why I ended up using the boot option that should make it persistent.